# Javascript 'reset' function not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Why am I required to click twice in order to change the classes after 'reseting'? How can I fix this issue?

The desired result is to bring the function back to the initial state and cycle through the arrays normally. Demo below.

```
$(function () {
    var weights = ["jHairline", "jThin", "jLight", "jMedium"];
    var currentIndex = 0;
    $('#text').on('click', function (e) {
        $("h1").removeClass().addClass(weights[currentIndex]);
        $("h1").html(weights[currentIndex]);

        if (currentIndex == weights.length - 1)
           currentIndex = 0;
        else
            currentIndex++;

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#reset').click(function () {
        currentIndex = 0;

        $("h1").removeClass().addClass(weights[currentIndex]);
        $("h1").html(weights[currentIndex]);
    });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/didacus/7pqybvh5/)

Comment: Initial state means "Weight" or "jHairline"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you reset it to 0 and don't increment it on the next update.
The quick fix would be

```
 $('#reset').click(function() {
    currentIndex = 0;

    $("h1").removeClass().addClass(weights[currentIndex]);
    $("h1").html(weights[currentIndex]);
    currentIndex=1;
  });
```

The proper way would be to do the incrementing at the beginning of the `$('#text').on('click', function(e) {` function

--Edit for clarification request--
This is how I would personally recommend writing it:

```
$(function () {
    var weights = ["jHairline", "jThin", "jLight", "jMedium"];
    var currentIndex = -1;
    $('#text').on('click', function (e) {
        currentIndex=(currentIndex+1)%weights.length;
        $("h1").removeClass().addClass(weights[currentIndex]);
        $("h1").html(weights[currentIndex]);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#reset').click(function () {
        currentIndex = 0;

        $("h1").removeClass().addClass(weights[currentIndex]);
        $("h1").html(weights[currentIndex]);
    });
});
```

The 2 lines I added/modified were `var currentIndex = -1;` and `currentIndex=(currentIndex+1)%weights.length;` .

So essentially, you are incrementing the number by 1 when the text.click function **starts**. If you start it at -1 at the beginning, then when text.click enters, it will increment it to 0. And setting it to 0 in reset will make sure it increments to 1 next time text.click is ran.

Further,

```
 if (currentIndex == weights.length - 1)
           currentIndex = 0;
        else
            currentIndex++;
```

is a bit more concise and clear when written as `currentIndex=(currentIndex+1)%weights.length;` . It is adding 1 to the number, and then modding (taking the remainder when dividing) to loop it back around to 0 once weight.length is hit.

Comment: It worked thank you. You mentioned fixing that at the beginning. How can I do that?

Comment: Thank you very much. Its this kind of explanation that really helps non-coders like me to understand things properly + learn how to improve their code. Thumbs up!

Comment: Sure :-) glad it helped you out